# Oracle Bulk in .Net Core

Tags: c#, oracle

We have an old project that was using ODP.NET (Oracle.DataAcess) targetting .NET Framework. We are porting that project to target .NET Core instead. So we removed the ODP.NET references and we used the newly [**Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core) that is compatible with .NET Core.

We noticed that it does not support `OracleBulkCopy` anymore. Is there any workaround to insert data as fast as `OracleBulkCopy` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that bulk copy will not be supported until 2020.

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=18357:39:1509910222252::NO::P39_ID:27881

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up re-implementing the bulk functionality completely using the [array binding feature](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/two-ways-to-insert-bulk-data-into-oracle-database-using-c-sharp/) of Oracle available in the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core`. The implementation offers the same APIs as the the original `Oracle.DataAccess`. Here is the decompiled code:

[image]

I also used [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) to stream the data and avoid accumulating the data on the server. The end result is as fast as the original `BulkCopy` function available in the Oracle.DataAccess DLL.

Comment: Do you have the source somewhere?

Comment: @AndrewHarry Unfortunately the source code is proprietary, but based on what I explained you could easily wire up some code that does exactly what you need.